# Can't succeed in using multiple textures in a fragment

Tags: java, android, opengl-es

In m y fragment shader, I declare an array of textures like this : `uniform sampler2D textures[7];`.

This array is loaded with the Open GL texture indices I want to use with : `GLES31.glUniform1iv(handleOnTextures, 7,new int [] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6);`

as I want to use `GL_TEXTURE0` to `GL_TEXTURE6`.

In my `onSurfaceCreated`function, I load textures in this way :

```
handleOnTextureNames= new int[textureArray.length];
GLES31.glGenTextures(textureArray.length, handleOnTextureNames, 0);
if (handleOnTextureNames[0] != 0) {
    options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inScaled = false;
    for (t = 0; t < textureArray.length; t++) {
        GLES31.glActiveTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE0+t);
        GLES31.glBindTexture(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, handleOnTextureNames[t]);
        image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(), textureArray[t], options);
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, image, 0);
        image.recycle();
    }
} else {
    throw new RuntimeException("Error!");
}

GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES31.GL_NEAREST);
GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES31.GL_NEAREST);
```

To define which texture I want to use during the execution of the shader, I transmit an indice to it with :

```
GLES31.glUniform1i(handleOnTextureIndice, idTexture);
```

with idTexture ranging from 0 to 6 depending on the texture I want to use.

In the fragment shader, to calculate the fragment color, the texture is accessed like this : `textures[textureIndice]`.

The problem I face is that only the last loaded texture gives a correct result and all others render as black!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your earlier textures are incomplete; you only specify the filtering parameters after the end of the loop, so only the last texture has the filtering defined.

Move this inside the loop where you set up each texture:

```
GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES31.GL_NEAREST);
GLES31.glTexParameteri(GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GLES31.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES31.GL_NEAREST);
```

Comment: It was so simple... Thanks for your efficient answer!